# Calculating spacecraft thrust manoeuvres with JPL data

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, rocket-science

I've recently programmed an animated simulation of the main elements (core planets and Sun) of our solar system: by using the initial coordinates from the JPL (Jet Propulsion Laboratory - NASA) database, and then calculating the combined gravitational perturbations and the relativistic effects from the Sun.

However I would now like to calculate the trajectories for both Voyager 1 & 2, and then map them onto my simulation. I can easily replicate the gravitational calculations used for the planets and the Sun, but I'm afraid I'm struggling to find, or figure out, how to replicate the various thrusts manoeuvres used throughout the voyagers' mission.

Any thoughts, insights or advice would be much appreciated, thank-you?

Current method: Calculate voyagers trajectory purely using gravitational effects and initial position/velocity, and then compare calculated data with JPL data, taking into account error, to calculate any unnatural changes in velocity (i.e. thrusts). The difficulty with this method however, is trying to derive meaningful data from the error comparison, any help here would also be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to space.stackexchange.com but the migration doesn't give that site as an option

Comment: The issue is that although I'm happy to post it to the space.SE, this site gets far more traffic (and the question is still very physics related), so I'm afraid my question will be more likely to go unanswered, if it is migrated across.

Comment: Many other questions on this site, also deal with thrust calculations, so it's not necessarily off topic, plus space.SE is still in it's beta format.

Comment: If you're trying to study new physics w.r.t. gravity (e.g Pioneer Anomaly), then this is physics. I was watching them talk to Voyager last week--I didn't see any joy-stick labeled  "Thrusters"

Comment: While the underlying problem is a physics problem, orbital maneuvering is pretty specialized. Almost all the users of [physics.se] will have no experience beyond what they got in upper-division or graduate mechanics (i.e. calculating Hohmann transfer parameters and similar problems). On the other hand, the  community at [space.se]—despite being smaller in overall size—likely has *more* people who have actual experience doing these calculation for 'real'.

Comment: @dmckee Thanks, if you believe that's the case, then I'll happily migrate the question across to space.SE

Comment: @JEB I'm sorry but could you please clarify what you meant by "I didn't see any joy-stick labeled "Thrusters" ", as I'm not too sure what you're trying to imply.

Comment: @Tarius I think I was gloating, cause I can hang here anytime-at the center of the universe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Flight_Operations_Facility

Comment: @JEB Ah I see, haha. I genuinely couldn't tell if you were by sarcastic or serious, but after looking at your profile, I see it was more of the latter than I expected :)